# Is marriage actually a sinful state?

Tags: marriage

Because the Gospels tell us that Jesus said, "In Heaven they neither marry nor are given in marriage but are like the angels..." Is He really stating that marriage is neither clean nor worthy of Heaven? I am reminded too that Jesus neither married nor preached marriage. Doesn't Christianity call on its followers to live the life that Jesus lived: in celibacy, poverty, community and confession? I'm not sure how Christians square marriage with that? The only Christians I'm aware of who live that life are some monastic sects, like Roman Catholic clergy and a few other, very small sects, like the Shakers.

> Matt 22:30 - In the resurrection, people will neither marry nor be
> given in marriage. Instead, they will be like the angels in heaven.

See also Mark 12:25, Luke 20:35.

Comment: Welcome to BH.se. The tradition here is to ask questions about specific verses and their interpretation. You question would be improved by citing chapter and verse and including the actual text for readers' reference. Please also take the Tour (link at bottom left) to get oriented.

Comment: Note the sentence "Instead, they will be like the angels in heaven". What is the gender of the angels?

Comment: Considering the fact that Jehovah God instituted the marriage arrangement (Genesis 2:24), it would be necessary to explain how marriage is sinful.

Comment: I up voted this because it is an interesting question. If the question could be re-framed as a question about hermenutical principles we could address it within the focus of this forum.

Comment: The question asserts because "X" - in this case marriage - is not in heaven but does exist on earth it must be a sin on earth. There are no tears in heaven - are tears on earth a sin? On earth we are called to forgive one another. There is no need to forgive in heaven so is forgiveness a sin? Something may exist on earth but is not needed in heaven. It is false to assume that anything that exists on earth but not in heaven is a sin on earth.

Answer (score 3):

Let us be very clear about the Bible's teaching about marriage:

- Heb 13;4 - Marriage should be honored by all and the marriage bed kept undefiled, for God will judge the sexually immoral and adulterers.
- 1 Cor 7:3-5 - The husband should fulfill his marital duty to his wife, and likewise the wife to her husband. The wife does not have authority over her own body, but the husband. Likewise the husband does not have authority over his own body, but the wife. Do not deprive each other, except by mutual consent and for a time, so you may devote yourselves to prayer. Then come together again, so that Satan will not tempt you through your lack of self-control.

Recall that it was the LORD Himself who performed the first wedding in Eden between Adam and Eve as recorded in -

> Gen 2:18 - The LORD God also said, “It is not good for the man to be
> alone. I will make for him a suitable helper.”
>
> Gen 2:24 - For this reason a man will leave his father and mother and
> be united to his wife, and they will become one flesh.

This is quoted by Matthew 19:5, Mark 10:7–8, 1 Corinthians 6:16, and Ephesians 5:31.

Having said that, there is no compulsion to be married - singleness is just as honorable as marriage.

> 1 Cor 7:8-10 - Now to the unmarried and widows I say this: It is good
> for them to remain unmarried, as I am. But if they cannot control
> themselves, let them marry. For it is better to marry than to burn
> with passion. To the married I give this command (not I, but the
> Lord): A wife must not separate from her husband. 11But if she does,
> she must remain unmarried or else be reconciled to her husband. And a
> husband must not divorce his wife.

So, why no marriage in heaven?  The simple answer is that that is the way God created things.  The longer answer might involve the question of population which heaven does not do; but this is debatable.

**APPENDIX - Bible teaching about marriage**

The Biblical data on marriage can be summarized as follows:

- Marriage is honorable (Matt 19:4-6, Mark 10:6-9, Heb 13:4, 1 Cor 7:14, Deut 24:5, Prov 5:18, 19, 12:4, 18:22, 19:14, 31:10) but not essential (1 Cor 7:7-9).
- In fact, Paul says by the Holy Spirit that in the last days (or latter times) there would arise liars and hypocrites who forbid marriage (1 Tim 4:1-3).
- Celibacy is an acceptable, even desirable, choice for some (Matt 19:12, 1 Cor 7:7, 8, 25-28, etc)
- Divorce is highly discouraged (Matt 5:31, 32, 19:6, 9, Mark 10:6-9, 1 Cor 7:11-13).  However, even Jesus’ advice in Matt 19:9 is moderated by verses 10-12 that “no divorce” is the ideal, but practical realities in a sinful world sometimes make divorce necessary.  Jesus said that the “Law” (= Torah) permitted divorce because of the hardness of your (sinful) hearts.  Sometimes, divorce is the “lesser of two evils” and this why it is not prohibited in Scripture.
- Divorce is permitted under some circumstances of “marital infidelity” (Matt 5:31, 32, 19:9, NIV), and the decision of an unbelieving spouse to leave (1 Cor 7:15).
- Separation, rather than divorce is sometimes appropriate (1 Cor 7:10, 11).
- Sex is a very important part of marriage (1 Cor 7:3, 4, Prov 5:18, 19, see also the entire book of Song of Solomon).  Sex has two functions – procreation (Gen 1:28) but much more importantly, bringing two people together and making them “one” (Gen 2:24, Matt 19:5, 6, Mark 10:8, 1 Cor 6:16, Eph 5:31).
- Marriage is the only place where sexual activity should occur (1 Cor 7:2).
- Wives must submit to (or obey) their husbands (Eph 5:22, 23, Col 3:18, 1 Peter 3:1, 5, 6) as is “appropriate” in the Lord – note that this is in the context of all Christians submitting to one another (Eph 5:21); BUT, -
- husbands must love their wives (Eph 5:22, Col 3:19, 1 Peter 3:7) and never be “harsh”, but treat them with consideration.  In fact, husbands must love their wives as much as Christ loved the church and gave Himself for her (Eph 5:25, 28, 29, 33).  Let us pause to note that some men, realising this awesome and frightening responsibility as husbands have been reticent to marry at all.  (This may have been part of the reason that Paul chose to remain unmarried, among other things.)
- All homosexual relationships are prohibited (Rom 1:26, 27, 1 Cor 6:9, 1 Tim 1:8-11, Jude 7 (cf. Gen 19:1-5), Lev 18:22, 20:13).  Note Paul’s comment in 1 Cor 6:11 – “and that is what some of you were.”  However, see “Eunuch” for further discussion on this difficult subject.
- Sexual immorality or fornication (Greek: “porneia”, John 8:41, Acts 15:20, 29, 21:25, 1 Cor 5:1, 6:13, 18, 2 Cor 12:21, Gal 5:19, Col 3:5, 1 Thess 4:3, Rev 2:21, 9:21, etc.) is any kind of illicit sex including heterosexual sex outside of marriage, adultery, homosexuality, bestiality, incest, etc.  The New Testament also specifically condemns adultery (Greek: moichos & moicheia), Matt 15:19, 5:27, 28, 32, 19:9, 18, Mark 7:21, 10:11, Luke 18:11, John 8:3, 1 Cor 6:9, Heb 14:4, etc.; it also forbids incest, 1 Cor 5.
- There will be no marriage in heaven, Matt 22:30, Mark 12:25, Luke 22:36.
- Marriage should be between people that are approximately “equal”, 2 Cor 6:14.  The context suggest that this is of spiritual and religious values.  However, if conversion of one partner occurred after marriage (due to one becoming Christian) then the marriage should not be dissolved (1 Cor 7:12-14, see also Rom 8:9) unless the unbelieving spouse leaves (V15, 16).

Answer (score 1):

No, Jesus was not saying that marriage was unclean or or sinful. It's not quite accurate to say he "never preached marriage." In teaching about divorce, he made it clear that marriage is a state blessed by God.

> 'For this reason a man shall leave his father and mother and be joined
> to his wife, and the two shall become one flesh’? 6 So they are no
> longer two but one flesh. Therefore what God has joined together, let
> no one separate.  - Matthew 19:5-6

Whether people married on earth will remain married in heaven is [much debated](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/74990/does-they-neither-marry-nor-are-given-in-marriage-refer-to-the-act-of-getting). I should mention that the Gospels do not state that Jesus was never married, although since they do speak of other family members, this is a logical inference.

Comment: Also Proverbs ch18 v22; "He who finds a wife finds a good thing and obtains favour from the Lord".

Comment: Yesterday I was walking in the forest at Seahurst Park. All I ran into was women with children. I asked three women where the men were and if there was a football game? The answer was startling. An angry middle aged woman turned on me and said "there are no men." Welcome to the new reality.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the answers that Dottard and Dan F have given, and I think they're substantially correct with regard to marriage as we understand and experience it. And certainly, Jesus is saying in Matthew 22 that the marriage covenant the way it exists between a man and his wife now will not exist in heaven—I will not be married to my wife.

However, to say there is no marriage in heaven full stop is to miss the point a bit. Marriage is inherently typological. This is why the Song of Songs, the Bible's book on marriage, can and must be read on multiple levels—man and woman, king and land, Yahweh and Israel, Christ and the church. Yahweh is the husband of his people Israel (Isaiah 54.5, Jeremiah 31.32), and Christ is Yahweh incarnate come to redeem his bride the church (Ephesians 5.32). We could say it like this: In heaven there will be no ("little m") marriage because all will be caught up in the ("big M") Marriage of the Lamb to his glorious Bride. To be sure, marriage is the story of the Bible from cover to cover, and the climax at the end of the book. Far from marriage being sinful, it is forever sanctified by the Lord's taking the church as his own bride.